# Cannot position divs correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div (gray background) at the top of my div-container and I can not make it match with the background-width size since there is a gap in the left side of the block.

Could someone explain me why?

```css
body {
    background-color: #a71930;
}
.container {
    height: 1200px;
    width: 1200px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
div#about {
    height: 400px;
    width: 1200px;
    background-color: #a5acaf;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
   

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="about"></div> 
  </div>
</body>
```

[codepan](https://ibb.co/dmJagF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your problem in codepen but there are couple of things that you can try here to fix this problem.

**1-** Reset the margin and padding of each `html` element to `0`. Add following code to your `CSS` file.

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }
```

**2-** Set the width of second `div` to `100%`

Answer (score 0):

use the css code

```
.container{padding:0px}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 'gap' you mentioned is just because you didn't reset the margins of your `<body>` tag.

Just set it to **0** like so:

```
body{margin: 0;}
```